# If category/page in wp_nav_menu exist

Tags: php, wordpress

I need your help

I have three custom menu(wp_nav_menu) which I customize via admin menu section.

```
<!-- first menu ->
    <?php companyMenu(); ?>
<!-- second menu ->
    <?php servicesMenu(); ?>
<!-- third menu ->
    <?php partnersMenu(); ?>
```

I want to show only one nav menu to which opened post/page/category belongs

For example: when I'm on home page click "Contacts" in menu it redirects me to "Contacts" page and because this page defined (with other menu links) in companyMenu() wp_nav_menu function it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really depend on how many pages you would need to check against for my solution to be viable- the fewer pages the better.

You could wrap your menu code in if statements and use the is_page wordpress function to check if you are on that page.  See the link below for more information.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Code Example

```
if(is_page( 'Contact' )){
servicesMenu();
}
```

As a general rule the wordpress codex has a great wealth of knowledge which I found really helpful when starting wordpress development

Comment: An alternative to checking by page title is checking for page template. Page templates are easily changed in admin and can be checked for with `is_page_template( my-page-template.php );`. That would mean creating additional template files, but they can be largely copied from the default and you can later change page titles.